# WCF Options when using Entity Framework on backend and WPF on front end

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wcf

I have been assigned the task of removing the WCF aspects of the solution and tp plug the GUI directly into Entity Framework objects. Currently the WCF service lives between the GUI (WPF) and any entity framework aspects.

I apologize for not being more knowledgeable about what I am asking about but I am brand new to these technologies. I am hoping that something "jumps right off the page" for some to give me answers about.

I am actively in the process of learning about these things and I have the application in a .sln file so I can dissect it in Visual Studio. Thanks in advance for any help.

The GUI needs to have controls bound to the data without using WCF, thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to your question, I assume you have two class libraries for WCF services, entity framework and a WPF application.

What you can do is create a mock class inside the WPF application and Entity framework class library to link both entity framework and WPF application.

The First step, implement methods inside the class of WPF application to call Entity framework class methods.

The Second step, implement methods inside Entity Framework mock class to communicate with entities and tables to retrieve values from the database through ADO Model.

Example :

**WPF Application Mock Class**

```
public class DBWrapper
{
    public bool AddCandidate(Candidate mCandidate)
    {
        DBAccess dba=new DBAccess();
        dba.AddCandidate(mCandidate);
    }
}
```

**Entity Framework Class Library Mock Class**

```
public class DBAccess
{
     public bool AddCandidate(Candidate mCandidate)
     {
          try
          {
             //Entity framework entities object instantiation
             var hrEntities=new HREntities();
             hrEntities.Candidate.Add(mCandidate);
             hrEntities.SaveChanges();
             return true; 
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
             return false;
          }
          return false;
     }
}
```

Hope this helps you.